# Unable to create directory

Tags: apache2, wordpress

Can help me anyone here ?

> Unable to create directory /srv/www/wp-uploads/localhost/2014/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Comment: what error it gives you

Comment: wordpress :D , i had upload header then i got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your question is very incomplete. Always remember to describe in detail what you have tried and what happened, along with any other info that you think may be necessary, while asking a question.

Looking at your tags and the message, it looks like your wordpress install is not able to accept file uploads.

This is a linux file system permissions issue. Check the permissions of the folder in the error message and all its parents. They should be writable by the user that apache is running as.

Assuming sane defaults, the user would be www-data. In that case,

```
sudo chown -R www-data /srv/www/wp-uploads
sudo chmod -R u+w /srv/www/wp-uploads
```

should do the trick.

Please verify your configuration, since improper usage of `sudo`, `chmod`, or `chown` can be dangerous, even more so when used together.

#### EDIT:

I totally forgot that this can be a improper wordpress configuration. It is entirely possible that you have chosen the wrong directory for file uploads in wordpress. In which case, [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/428303/45659) is the one you should be looking at.

You can leave the current configuration as-is, in which case all uploads go to `/srv/www/wp-uploads` or change the uploads directory to a better* value like `wp-content/uploads`, copy over all files in `/srv/www/wp-uploads` and delete the latter.

*better because the uploads live inside the wordpress install directory, instead of web root. It is also a common practice.

Comment: chmod: cannot access `www-data': No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. That www-data was not needed there. Edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Miscellaneous Setting :

[image]

Just be sure there is not **/** before **wp-content**